# How can I flip desktops between two displays in OSX

Tags: macos, display, mission-control

I have a multi monitor setup, and I want the ability to flip the desktop being displayed on my primary monitor and the desktop being displayed on my secondary monitor.

I know this is a strange request, but I'm often engaged in video conferencing, I want the ability to remain looking at my camera while moving to work on related tasks. Is there anyway to code this type of macro, or is this a feature in OSX?

Thanks!

Comment: In what way would you like to flip the displays? Would you like to change the primary display or move all the windows from one display to another?

Comment: I like Monomeeth's answer, but you can also just go to mission control (3 finger swipe up) and move the desktop you are working on to the other monitor

Comment: I am looking for a similar functionality to the control + arrow hotkey that allows me to move between desktops on my primary display. Except I would like this functionality to switch the desktop I am displaying on my primary monitor and the one on my secondary monitor. So lets say my primary monitor has desktops 1-5 and secondary monitor has desktops 6 and 7. Monitor 1 has Desktop 1 active. Monitor 2 has Desktop 6 Active. I would like a quick command to move desktop 1 to Monitor 2 and Desktop 6 to Monitor 1. I know I can drag and drop them back and forth, but I would like to make it faster

Comment: it's 2023 and unfortunately OSX still does not have this feature

Answer (score 3):

If what you want to do is just to swap your screens around, then you can do this with the Displays pane in System Preferences. More specifically:

- Go to Apple Menu > System Preferences
- Select **Displays**
- Click the **Arrangement** tab
- Click and drag the display(s) to rearrange them as you wish. You can also rearrange which one has the menu bar.

If instead you wanted to do something else, please clarify your question so I (or someone else) can help you.

In the meantime, you may want to read: [use multiple displays with your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT202351).

Comment: I am looking for a similar functionality to the control + arrow hotkey that allows me to move between desktops on my primary display. Except I would like this functionality to switch the desktop I am displaying on my primary monitor and the one on my secondary monitor. So lets say my primary monitor has  desktops 1-5 and secondary monitor has desktops 6 and 7. Monitor 1 has Desktop 1 active. Monitor 2 has Desktop 6 Active. I would like a quick command to move desktop 1 to Monitor 2 and Desktop 6 to Monitor 1.

I know I can drag and drop them back and forth, but I would like to make it faster